# Our application is responding different on client server

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net

I have an application running on our local server and it works perfect.

However when I deploy my application to our client's server there are problems.
If i copy all the sources to another local from their server, it works fine again....
I am talking about an ASP.NET application talking with windows server 2008.

The server specs of our client are:

> intel Xeon 2.13 GHz 6 GB RAM 300 GB HDD windows server 2008 R2

Although I think it's not that important

I will describe the problems I am talking about to give u a better idea:

It is related to upating and deleting fields in the sql server. Whenever there is more than one user running the application, and updates or deletes (not even the same record!0, there seems to be fields updating/deleting wrongly.

But as I said before, if we copy the source to another server it is not the case. So I assumed it is more configuration related. Do you guys have any idea what the issue could be?

Thanks a lot

EDIT: my client old me he disabled the sql related accounts

Could this be related?

EDIT EDIT: 
I have a screen with a gridview, each row resembles a different type of clothing.
If I press on the row, it opens a new screen where I can upload/delete an image. However this screen only saves it in the database after pressing a save button. It writes it as blob storage.
If somebody also opens a screen to upload or delete an image (not necessarily the same clothing), sometimes, the images are wrongly updated or deleted. This issue ONLY happens on their configured server, and nowhere else. So it has to be related to some sort of user handling configuration or some sort.

Comment: can you elaborate on the issues that are arising ?

Comment: That sounds more like an error in how the code is handling the save. Since the data, in this case, images, are being saved in relation to the wrong row that you clicked on, something is giving you the wrong state (row) reference. I would start by checking to see if your clicked on row is giving you the expected output first. IE. just update a label with the row id when it's clicked on, compare the values on your server and then on the client server.

Comment: Yes that's what we thought at first, but after we copy all the code to another server it works fine

Comment: So you're seeing different onclick values on one server than another?

Comment: please view my EDIT EDIT :)

Comment: Right, and I was asking if you could see what those output values are on the problem server vs the working ones. If you can see what the problem server is doing, then you can narrow down where the problem is. Find some way to debug the code on the problem server and you'll find your answer.